# How to inhibit formation of specific antibodies (to antisera)?

Tags: immunology, biotechnology, antibody, antigen, mouse

Is there a way to inhibit an antibody response to a specific antigen using immunosupression? I am interested in reducing the anti-antibody formation to animal antibodies such as murine antibodies in antisera.

I have read that there are ways to decrease the immune response to antisera but haven't found a detailed paper on how they work.

Update 12/3/2014: Would this work? http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2374127/pdf/0100491.pdf
Although it is streptavidin, could a similar process be used for antibodies?

Comment: Related [post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17296/why-is-there-no-way-to-remove-an-immune-response)

Comment: Are you asking about *in vitro* or *in vivo*?

Comment: in vivo... if possible...

Comment: As far as I know there is no way, except for suppressing the immune response at all. If it were possible, this would be a great help against autoimmune diseases.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to reducing the titer in the immunized animal, you could give the animal a drug that has immunosuppressive properties. Velcade (PS-341) is a drug that effectively reduces plasma cell counts. There are many immunosuppressive drugs available.

If you  want to reduce the antibodies affinity, you are undertaking a much more delicate process. Affinity can be transiently affected by introducing a  unfavorable environment for the antibody. You can accomplish this by changing the temp, salt conditions, pH or introducing a denaturing agent like guanidine HCL.

Changing any of these conditions in just a little excess could also result in a permanent reduction in affinity.

If you are attempting to tailor the affinity constant of the Ab by changing the architecture of the antigen, you are correct this can be done using site directed mutagenesis. However I think it would be more effective to perform a random mutagenesis and then screen the mutants for the *Ka* value you want.

Lastly the antigen could also be post-translationally modified. After performing *in vitro* transcription and translation you could modify your antigen using different strategies such as ubiquination, phosphorylation, prenylation etc... All these could potentially affect *Ka* as well.

A Hybridoma system to produce a monoclonal antibody should also be explored. Here is a reputable company that produces monoclonal antibodies:

http://www.sdix.com/Products/Custom-Antibody-Services/Ab-Production-and-Services/mAb-Antibody-Development/Hybridoma-Development.aspx

Comment: Hello @rhill45 , I did read about reducing immune response to an antiserum so I would like more info on that.. but otherwise, thanks for the info... BTW, can site directed mutagenesis and ubiquination, phosphorylation, prenylation etc. be used to change the Fc region of an antibody? Can it  also be used to chimerize the antibody?

Comment: @TAbraham check this out http://m.peds.oxfordjournals.org/content/23/4/289

Comment: Chimerize the ab?? To the antigen? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to decrease the immune response to foreign antibodies (this is why i was talking about anti-sera) so the antigen would be the foreign antibody...

Comment: Also, would creating antibodies against the antibody-producing cells work?

Comment: If you are creating an antibody against another antibody what you are creating is called a secondary antibody. If you want to decrease antibody production in a host the way to do that is through immunocompromising  the host. That are many ways to do this with varying specificity: radiation, chemicals, viral infections, giving the host certain cancers; even an autoimmune disease could work I guess. Let me know what I'm missing in my answer to get it marked. Using Cyclosporine is going to be your easiest and most well studied method.

Comment: I am trying decrease the production of secondary antibodies...

Comment: @T ABraham Let me know what my answer is missing to get marked as correct.

Comment: are there any other studied ways to decrease the production of secondary antibodies? It seems cyclosporin won't work... I want the most specific way to do so if possible... BTW, Thnx for your answer...

Comment: Velcade is a proteosome inhibitor that is very specific for lowering plasma cell concentration (these are the cells producing the antibody).  Have you looked at a Hybridoma system to make a polyclonal secondary antibody?

Comment: What do you mean about polyclonal secondary antibody? i know about hybridoma systems for monoclonal antibodies but don't fit my needs... I am trying to stay away from chimeric and humanized antibodies as well...

Comment: Oops meant monoclonal (sorry iPhone)

Comment: also, I don't want to use hybridomas because it would take away the reason for the project I am using this info for...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19372/discussion-between-t-abraham-and-rhill45).

Comment: Would you like to talk in chat?