# How can site-directed mutagenesis be used to suppress the production of anti-antibodies?

Tags: immunology, biotechnology, antibody

In a previous post of mine, I asked how to supress the creation of anti-antibodies in vivo. In the answer, it was mentioned that site-directed mutagenesis could be used. Currently, I can't find mcuh on how to do so... How does this work?

Update: As people want to know where this idea is coming from, here is the link to my previous question about it.. look in the answer for more info:

[How to inhibit formation of specific antibodies (to antisera)?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/24483/how-to-inhibit-formation-of-specific-antibodies-to-antisera)

Comment: Could you link to your previous post for context? Site-directed mutagenesis is nearly impossible to perform *in vivo*, so I'm wondering what the comment poster was getting at...

Comment: You want to do site-directed mutagenesis in unspecified living cells in a living body? How do you want to select the cells which make the auto-antibody? This will never work.

Comment: @Chris it was just a comment provided by the answer for my previous question.. I will give you the link